# Use a AC plugged device with a battery

Tags: batteries, ac, dc

I have an electronic drumkit, which is plugged to the AC plug.
I want to put it in a room without any access to the AC grid, and I would want to use batteries instead.

The device is called Roland Td15, and from what I read in the manual, it uses a DC 9V, with 450mA current draw. Here is a link to the complete pdf [manual](https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/TD-15_11_OM.pdf). It says the adapter used is "PSB 1U".

My question is how to use a battery (or AA batteries if possible) ? Is it as simple as getting 6 AA batteries in series with the right DC plug ? Are there some point I should be aware of ?

I saw products like [this one](https://www.joom.com/en/products/1511234169247348171-239-1-26193-1900499024), maybe it is enough, what do you think ?

Have a nice day !

Comment: 6 x AA will be fully drained in about 3 hours. Consider more powerfull battery.

Comment: Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.

Comment: a life battery pack at 7.4v is probably enough voltage. if not, add a DC-DC buck+boost to it, then you can feed it any voltage from anywhere (within reason).

Comment: Voted to reopen because the question is *technical in nature* (how to use a battery) and not product oriented (what brand of battery to use). You guys need to chill.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the run time you want.

- An AA alkaline battery has about 2500 mAh capacity. At 450mA, the batteries would be depleted in about 2500/450 = **5.5 hours.**
- D alkaline batteries are 12 ~ 18 Ah, and would last between **26 and 40 hours** run time. This is probably more cost-effective than running AA's.

Have more of a budget and want a longer run time? Get a car adapter for the Roland and use a 12V-type car battery.

- Adapter: https://www.directnine.fr/products/myvolts-9v-incar-power-supply-adaptor-compatible-with-roland-td15-drum-module
- A 'Group 35' auto battery (typical small car): about 50Ah, which stepped down to 9V is abut 77 Ah. Run time would be about **111 hours**.

Comment: I agree with the 9V adapter with a 12V battery. You can get a jumper battery that is easily charged with AC mains while you are not using it and can provide power for other things as well. Some even come with 200W inverters and you wouldn't need the adapter for that. This is a robust option that doubles to start your car after leaving your lights on during your jam session.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AA batteries but that would be a pain to take out of whatever battery container, recharge the batteries, and then put them back into the case. I'm a lazy person and I like things easy, that doesn't sound easy.

You could also use some king of DC-DC adapter. So you need 9V but for example you could use a 5V power supply no problem, using something like this USB cable adapter: https://www.amazon.ca/current-Negative-Connector-compatible-effects/dp/B07GD54Q66

USB to 9V with 800mA output (@9V). Now all you need is a decent USB power bank.

You could also mod the cable to make it a proper USB-C cable so you don't have to fiddle with the up/down orientation and get yourself one of those USB-C powerbanks with quickcharge.

Does this help? I've got other ideas I could suggest.

Comment: I think the ad copy is misleading and that both ends have a current limit of 800ma, which means the 9v limit is more like 500ma. I have a 12v one and it goes into OCP at even 500ma. That said, wall wort current ratings are worst-case, so the music device very well could work with a lot less than 450ma...